# View data of a table inside another tablespace

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table `EMPLOYEE` inside the `EMPLOYEE` schema, which is inside the default user tablespace `USERSPACE1`.

I have now created a new tablespace using the following command:

`CREATE TABLESPACE HQ`

I then used `ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE` command in the following way to copy my table to the new tablespace

`CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE('EMPLOYEE' , 'EMPLOYEE' , 'HQ' , 'HQ' , 'HQ' , '', '', '', '', '', 'MOVE')`

The status shows `COMPLETE` after running this command.

Now I run the following command to check whether my table has been copied into the new tablespace or not:

`select TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, TBSPACEID, TBSPACE from syscat.tables`

This does show my `EMPLOYEE` table inside `EMPLOYEE` schema inside the `HQ` tablespace.

I now have a few queries:

1. I inserted a new record into the `EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE` table. Where did the new record insert - in the `USERSPACE1` tablespace or the `HQ` tablespace
2. How do I view records in the `EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE` table inside both the tablespaces?

Comment: `ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE` does not `COPY` a table it `MOVE`s a table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with some basics on a high level:

- A schema is like a logical directory or folder.
- A tablespace is providing the storage space (and it can be spread over several disks).
- A table holds data of the same structure and needs to be in a schema. The table data is stored in a tablespace. (It is far more complex, but...)

Coming back to your questions:

If the table stores its data in the HQ tablespace, all its data is in that space. Thus, you see all the data from all the tablespaces which is a single tablespace.